# How to remove script manager from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I have a script manager in base page. I want to remove the scriptmanager in some pages.

I tried the below code

```
 ScriptManager scr = System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
 this.Page.Controls.Remove(scr);
```

But it is not removing the scriptmanager.
Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Removve the control from web.config. It's called `System.Web.Extensions`

Look for this line and comment out or remove:

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```